ChartJS Pie chart with react-chartjs-2 Legend align to the right error
I am trying to create a Pie chart in react using react-chartjs-2 and chartjs.
For that I'm using  "chart.js": "^4.4.3", "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0"
The problem is when I use Legend position other than top and bottom (left/right) I get this error:

legendItemText.reduce is not a function
TypeError: legendItemText.reduce is not a function
at calculateItemWidth (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76769:37)

import { Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";

import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
    PointElement,
    PieController,    
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
    PointElement,
    PieController,
);

function PieChart({chartData}){

    const options={
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        plugins:{
            title:{
                display:true,
                text:"Users Gained between 2016-2020"
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                rtl: false,
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    pointStyle: 'rect',
                    textAlign: 'middle',
                },
            }
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                bottom: 6,
                left: 30,
                right: 30,
                top: 6
            }
        }
    };

    
    return(<Pie data={chartData} options ={options}/>);
}

export default PieChart;

Any Ideas on how to solve this? thank you for the help.
Best regards,
Note: I have tried almost every example that I could find.
Could someone point me in the right direction so I can solve this?
I have already done that with jQuery but I can't do it with React.

I can't reproduce your error; but I suspect the issue is with your data.labels - it might contain numbers or something else than strings or array of strings - it it is the case, convert the numbers/values explicitly to strings; if not, please post a sample data object.   The function that generates the error, calculateItemWidth is called just for a vertical legend and not for a horizontal one, but the issue is that legendItem.text (set from data.labels) is not a string or array as expected.

Hi, Thank you very much that was it! my data.labels was in did numbers :) Once more thank you.

Although the error appears to be related to the legend plugin, the actual cause is in the data: namely that some of the datasets labels contain values of other types than string, or array of string for multi-line labels.
The most common case (confirmed by the OP to be the case in their code too) is that some datasets labels data.datasets.label are of type number. Numeric labels are indeed seamlessly converted to strings, except for the case when there is a legend with a vertical layout (that is, a legend positioned to the left or to the right, not top/bottom).
The solution is to make those labels to be strings: either use a string literal ("2" instead of 2) or use .toString() if the labels come from an external source.
The explanation of this behavior is this: the error legendItemText.reduce is not a function is produced in the function calculateItemHeight (see source code). That function is only called for a vertical legend, and not for a horizontal one that uses different functions to compute the space it will occupy. Now, as we can see from the source code, it expects that
each legendItem.text to be either a string or an Array. It can be also verified in the same source file, that when there's no legend label callback, the text property of the legendItems is taken directly from corresponding datasets[meta.index].label.

Thank you! I've had the same issue and with your answer i was able to locate the issue. A simple casting to string for all data labels fixed it for me! This should be the accepted answer.
